# Create number sequence based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to generate number sequence based on 2 columns, Sno and UnitCost. The numbers should run down sequentially but they shouldn't change when both the columns are same. But if any one column is different it should increment.

I tried something with `row_number()`, `rank()`, `dense_rank()` but have been unable to hit the right logic.

Here's the required column and existing columns:

```
Sno    UnitCost   RequiredColumn
ch01   10         01
ch01   10         01
ch02   20         02
ch02   20         02
ch02   30         03
ch02   30         03
ch03   10         04
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
SELECT Sno, UnitCost, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sno, UnitCost) RequiredColumn
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unnecessarily sneaking in the partition clause as well. Trying some sql after long :)